# Upgrade from Wheezy to Stretch now reports itself as sid?

Tags: debian, debian-stretch

On one of our servers, I tried to install Python 3.7.1 from source. The compile failed because of dependency problems. So, I thought: "Oh, it's still Debian 8. I'll upgrade to 9, and try again."
I followed [this guide](https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-upgrade-debian-8-jessie-to-debian-9-stretch), which I have used over and over with consistent success.

When I got to the last `apt dist-upgrade`, it failed with a `ModuleNotFound` error because it couldn't find debconf.py. I realized that it was upset over the previous attempt to install Python 3.7, so I recompiled.

Python compiled just fine, but debconf.py was still not available. I used `locate` to find it, and symlinked the previous python3 version into the python path, re-rand it, and everything worked.

**Here's the problem:**

When I run `lsb_release -a` It now reports itself as sid - even though the original install was wheezy and the upgrade was to stretch. So, something is either *very* broken, or this can be ignored.

I have no idea where to go from here, but seems like this needs to be fixed.

What's the next step?

**Update**

As requested, my apt sources list:

```
#deb http://debian.gtisc.gatech.edu/debian/ wheezy main contrib non-free
#deb-src http://debian.gtisc.gatech.edu/debian/ wheezy main contrib non-free
#
#deb http://security.debian.org/ wheezy/updates main contrib non-free
#deb-src http://security.debian.org/ wheezy/updates main contrib non-free
#
## wheezy-updates, previously known as 'volatile'
#deb http://debian.gtisc.gatech.edu/debian/ wheezy-updates main contrib non-free
#deb-src http://debian.gtisc.gatech.edu/debian/ wheezy-updates main contrib non-free
#
## wheezy-backports
##deb http://http.debian.net/debian/ wheezy-backports main contrib non-free

deb http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ stretch main contrib non-free
deb-src http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ stretch main contrib non-free


deb http://httpredir.debian.org/debian stretch-updates main contrib non-free
deb-src http://httpredir.debian.org/debian stretch-updates main contrib non-free


deb http://security.debian.org/ stretch/updates main contrib non-free
deb-src http://security.debian.org/ stretch/updates main contrib non-free

deb-src http://http.debian.net/debian stretch main

deb http://hwraid.le-vert.net/debian stretch main
```

Comment: Do you also have files in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d`?

Comment: No, nothing in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d`.